# How can I catch a yii2 encrypted hash url in route

Tags: php, routes, yii2

I have a encrypted hash for the user reset password link which goes something like this:

http://my.doma.in/reset-password/l0SASiqG7-poflus+S6KHN3WU8QN9lasGr8yka/GMnvSA==133814

I want to catch all the request to the /reset-password and redirect it to /account-reset-password

But what is happening is that Yii2 thinks the / and other special characters as pathnames or variables and throw an error like this:

> exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to
>   resolve the request "reset-password/".' in

This is the relevant code in the urlmanager section of my config.php

```
'reset-password/<key>' => '/site/reset-password',
```

I believe that something needs to got in  or similar to consume everything that comes after reset password. Could someone throw some light on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need URL encode the Base64 encoding.